# waiting for connection netbeans xdebug codeigniter xampp

Tags: codeigniter, netbeans, xampp

While debugging in net beans code of php i got this message waiting for connection netbeans xdebug. I tried to resolve it but it wasn't work.Please help. i asm using xampp server on my localhost.

Comment: Please share code what you have tried

Comment: Hello Ali i just trying to debug PHP code in netbeans but it says waiting for connection